# Postgres aggregate function by date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables. The first is named page with the schema id and name. The second table is page_counts. It has the schema id, page_id (foreign key to page table), views, and date. Basically, I'm tracking how many views some pages get every single day. Views for each day are cumulative, so it will always be equal to or greater than views for the previous day.

I want to be able to track how many views a page gets by week. This comes down to taking the most recent day's views and subtracting from that the total number of views from a week before that day. I want to be able to do this over multiple weeks as well, so finding out the total number of views for the past week, total number starting from last week and going back one more week etc.

I looked into the postgres date functions, but not much is making sense. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to do it without data to test but it should be something like this

```
select page_id, week,
    views - lag(views, 1, 0) over (partition by page_id order by week) as views
from (
    select page_id, date_trunc('week', "date") as week, max(views) as views
    from page_counts pc
    group by 1, 2
) s
order by 1, 2 desc
```

The subquery just groups by page and week getting the corresponding maximum number of views.

Then the [`lag`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) window function get the number of views from the previous week for that page.